# Android custom ArrayAdapter rendering Objects in list, not values

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I'm trying to bind a custom layout (a LinearLayout containing two TextViews) to a Spinner. I subclassed ArrayAdapter (mostly) correctly. Selecting an item in the Spinner calls getView() correctly, setting the LinearLayout's TextViews' values correctly. The problem is the initial display of the items in the Spinner (when clicking on the Spinner) just shows Objects; not the TextViews they should be displaying. Only AFTER clicking on one of the Objects does the Spinner correctly set the TextViews using my custom adapter's getView() method. Here's the custom adapter class:

```
public class BusRouteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BusRoute> {
...
public BusRouteAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewId, ArrayList<BusRoute> routes) {
    super(context, resource, textViewId, routes);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    BusRoute route = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.bus_route, parent, false);
    }
    TextView tvBusRoute = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvBusRoute);
    TextView tvBusRouteNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvBusRouteNumber);
    tvBusRoute.setText(route.routeName); 
    tvBusRoute.setTag(route.route);
    tvBusRouteNumber.setText(route.route);
    if (!route.routeColor.equals("")) {
        tvBusRouteNumber.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(route.routeColor));
    }
    return convertView;
}
}
```

Here's the layout that is to be used for each Spinner list item (bus_route.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBusRouteNumber"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:padding="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBusRoute"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:padding="8dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And in my Activity, I'm setting the adapter to a properly-populated list of BusRoute objects:

```
busRouteAdapter = new BusRouteAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.bus_route, R.id.tvBusRoute, arrayOfBusRoutes);
        routesSpinner.setAdapter(busRouteAdapter);
```

It does seem strange that I need to pass the Layout id (R.layout.bus_route) AND one of the TextViews contained in that Layout (R.id.tvBusRoute).

Here's what is rendered when clicking on the Spinner:

[image: popup list when Spinner is clicked]

But if I click one of the Objects, getView() is called, and the selected Layout and TextViews are rendered properly (apparently I selected "GMU - Pentagon"):

[image: selected item]

What am I missing to get the Spinner's popup list to display ALL my bus route items rendered correctly?

Comment: You've not overridden `getDropDownView()`, so, by default, it's displaying the `toString()` return of your `BusRoute` objects in the `TextView` whose ID you passed in the constructor. You've apparently not overridden `toString()` in `BusRoute`, so that's why you get the `Object` `toString()` there.

Comment: @mike-m Ah, right. So when I override toString() in BusRoute, how do I specify a meaningful result since I need to parse the BusRoute object to be displayed in different TextViews? I assume I can display the richly-formatted TextViews I've defined in the popup list from the Spinner?...

Comment: Overriding `toString()` won't fix your whole issue. That was just to explain why you're seeing that in the dropdown items. You would need to handle your item `View` in `getDropDownView()` like you are in `getView()`. In fact, you can probably just `return getView(position, convertView, parent);` in `getDropDownView()`, if you want those to look exactly the same.

Comment: @MikeM. Bless you. That was it. I googled the hell out of this, but nowhere did I see a reference to overriding getDropDownView(). I did that, set the values accordingly, and it's working.  Damn, that was simple. Thank you thank you thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to override getDropDownView to deal with spinners

```
  @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             BusRoute route = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.bus_route, parent, false);
    }
    TextView tvBusRoute = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvBusRoute);
    TextView tvBusRouteNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvBusRouteNumber);
    tvBusRoute.setText(route.routeName); 
    tvBusRoute.setTag(route.route);
    tvBusRouteNumber.setText(route.route);
    if (!route.routeColor.equals("")) {
        tvBusRouteNumber.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(route.routeColor));
    }
    return convertView;

        }
```